# Python: How to extract Drive from Filepath string

Tags: python, string, split

If there a pre-defined single-line easy to remember python command that extracts a drive letter from a string filepath useful on both mac and windows?

if MAC:

```
filepathString = '/Volumes/Some Documents/The Doc.txt'
```

would result to :

```
myDrive = '/Volumes/transfer'
```

if WIN:

```
filepathString = 'c:\Some Documents\The Doc.txt'
```

would result to :

```
myDrive = 'c:'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [`splitdrive`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive) method from the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module along with the regular [`split`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split). It's not single line, but then again I can't see how the code would know to append `transfer` to the volume path, or detect if a given path is from Windows or Unix (remember `C:` is a valid Unix filename).

Answer (score 6):

Pathlib now has a property `drive` which makes this really easy by calling `path.drive`

###### Full Example:

```py
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(r'F:\\test\folder\file.txt')
path.drive
```

[PathLib Documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.drive)

Answer (score 3):

Simple example(Windows):

```
import os
import pathlib
drive = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd()).parts[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going to have to write custom code for this. Use `platform.system()` or `platform.uname()` to find out what kind of system you're on, then use `os.path` functions to extract the drive/volume name in a way appropriate to the detected platform.

A sketch:

```
def volume_name(path):
    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        return re.search("^\/Volumes\/[^/]+/", path).group(0)
    elif platform.system() == "Windows":
        return path[0:2]
```